# How do I click a list item and show it's parents?

Tags: jquery

sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/UCgFa/11/

I am trying to select a list item and display it, and it's parents in the hierarchy.

### HTML:

```
  <div class="wayfinder"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="name">Start state</span>

            <ul class="show">
                <li><span class="name">Superstate 1</span>

                    <ul class="show">
                        <li><span class="name">Start Cycle</span>

                            <ul class="show">
                                <li><span class="name">task 1 </span>

                                </li>
                                <li><span class="name">task 2 </span>

                                </li>
                                <li><span class="name">task 3 </span>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="name">X-fer to dal</span>
        </li>
        <li><span class="name">end cycle</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

### jQuery

```
$(".name").click(function () {
    var bread = $(this).parents()
        .map(function () {
        return this.text();
    }).get().join("> ");
    $('.wayfinder').text(bread);
});
```

the result for example if I clicked 'task 2' would be: Start state > Superstate1 >Start Cycle>Task 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$(".name").click(function () {
    var bread = $(this).add($(this).parents('ul').not($(this).closest('ul')).find('.name:first')).map(function () {
      return $(this).text();
  }).get().join(" > ");
  $('.wayfinder').text(bread);
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UCgFa/16/)**

**UPDATE**

If you want to limit the number of breadcrumbs, the easy way would be to limit the parents selector to only the first 2 parents with `.parents('ul:lt(3)')` so you'll get at max 3 labels, but if you want something a little more fancy like `My furthest parent > ... > My parent > Me` you can use something like this:

```
$(".name").click(function () {
  var bread = $(this).add($(this).parents('ul').not($(this).closest('ul')).find('.name:first')).map(function(){return $(this).text();}).get();
  if(bread.length > 3){
      bread.splice(1,bread.length-3, '...');
  }
  bread = bread.join(' > ');
  $('.wayfinder').text(bread);
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UCgFa/19/)**

Comment: this works GREAT, is there a way I can limit it to show the last three labels if I am dealing with too many nested items to fit on a line?

Comment: on implementing this for some reason it skips the second list item in the dom -wierd. I had another idea :After trying a number of things I thought it might even be ultra simple if I just listed the whole dom list and have it slice off the remainder after the current matching text

Comment: check your markup and make sure it is the same for all list items, the key part is the span with the class "name", also I'm not sure if your new approach would work, but you should still try it :)

Comment: @kola_dev [link]http://jsfiddle.net/UCgFa/24/ this is the full dom -I was trying not to oversimplify in my above example but it does reproduce here. the '.name' is a second class added to that span.

Comment: there was an issue with the styles in your fiddle, try this one http://jsfiddle.net/UCgFa/27/ and tell me if you encounter the same problem, are you having trouble getting the bread text to show or getting the right parents?

Comment: it's looks like it's still doing it -the challenge posed for me was that the link itself cannot be clicked to get the text() because clicking the link directly is used to take the user to another place. What happens is the 'superstate' keeps getting skipped over.

Comment: @namretiolnave try this one http://jsfiddle.net/UCgFa/28/ I changed the selector to look for <li> instead of <ul>

Comment: this is definitely better -it does skip over the 'start state' but I think might be ok since the reason I need this is to make breadcrumbs for the collapsed content to show the user where they are

Comment: @namretiolnave I see, well it is skipped because in the markup 'start state' is not a parent of the other elements, you may try adding other custom selectors in the code besides `parents` if you want to leave your markup the way it is

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work with the <li> row being clicked to find the .name span

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript has an error that shows up, you needed quotes around "this" on this.text

I've modified it like so:

```
$(".name").click(function() {

   var bread = $(this).parents().map(function () {
   return $(this).text();
}).get().join("> ");

$('.wayfinder').text(bread);
});
```

In your JSFiddle and it looks like that's what you want and that JSFiddle is putting some extra stuff in there you probably won't see in your actual site.